# tf.contrib.learn load_csv_with_header not working in TensorFlow 1.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I installed the latest TensorFlow (v1.1.0) and I tried to run the [tf.contrib.learn Quickstart](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn) tutorial, where you suppose to build a classifier for the IRIS data set. However, when I tried:

```
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32)
```

I got a `StopIteration` error.

When I checked the API, I didn't find anything about the `load_csv_with_header()`. Have they changed it in the latest version without updating the tutorial? How can I fix this?

**EDIT**:
I use Python3.6 if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of the difference between Python 2 and Python 3. Here's my code below that works for Python 3.5:

```
if not os.path.exists(IRIS_TRAINING):
    raw = urllib.request.urlopen(IRIS_TRAINING_URL).read().decode()
    with open(IRIS_TRAINING, 'w') as f:
        f.write(raw)

if not os.path.exists(IRIS_TEST):
    raw = urllib.request.urlopen(IRIS_TEST_URL).read().decode()
    with open(IRIS_TEST, 'w') as f:
        f.write(raw)
```

What probably happened is that your code created a file name after `IRIS_TRAINING`. But the file is empty. Thus `StopIteration is raised`. If you look into the implementation of `load_csv_with_header`:

```
with gfile.Open(filename) as csv_file:
    data_file = csv.reader(csv_file)
    header = next(data_file)
```

`StopIteration` is raised when `next` does not detect any additional items to read as documented https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration

Note the change in my code compared to the Python 2 version as shown in Tensorflow tutorial:

1. `urllib.request.urlopen` instead of `urllib.urlopen`
2. `decode()` is performed after `read()`

Comment: I actually just made it work by looking at @Alexandre's answer. Indeed the file was empty, and when I downloaded it manually, it worked. I tried to use the `request` myself, but I had no idea about the `decode()` at the end. So, your answer will be accepted since it gives the solution to the downloading problem.

Comment: yeah you need `decode` because of the difference between `str` and `byte` type in Python 3. `read()` return `byte` while `write()` expects `str`

Answer (score 2):

`StopIteration` should only happen there if the csv file is empty. Did you check that that path (IRIS_TRAINING) resolves to something you have permission to open?

Answer (score 0):

or you can write the csv file as binary instead of adding `decode()`

```
if not os.path.exists(IRIS_TRAINING):
    raw = urllib.request.urlopen(IRIS_TRAINING_URL).read()
    with open(IRIS_TRAINING, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(raw)
```

Answer (score -1):

if the answer above doesn't work, you may specify your path of the iris_training.csv and iris_test.csv file in the urlopen() method.